# How is the value of the "unique partition GUID" is generated?

Tags: uefi, gpt

From UEFI spec 2.8, GPT partition entry array definition (5.3.3), I understand that Unique Partition GUID is to "uniquely identify every partition that will ever be created". And the language seemingly implies there can be a pool of GUIDs or some default GUID generator. Then where does this pool/generator usually reside? (tool lib like fdisk? media firmware? I don't think it's in BIOS or kernel from what I read.)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1010587/is-there-are-way-to-calculate-the-guids-for-a-gpt-partition-table the first answer explains it. It's random. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_entries explains it well. 16 byte partition type ID + 16 byte uhique guid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tool that creates the new partition also generates the GUID for it. `fdisk` [uses](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/cd313d30952ec43554fde087a86087b615124825/libfdisk/src/gpt.c#L2563) the [`uuid_generate_random`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/uuid_generate.3.html) function from libuuid for that.

If you are interested in details, [RFC 4122](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122) describes UUIDs in more details and also includes description of algorithms to create them. (UUID and GUID are more or less synonyms, there are some differences, if you are interested in details, I recommend [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6953207/586192)).

Comment: Thanks, that solves the puzzle.